# SQL error that i could not figure it out

Tags: php, sql

## This is the code:

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8', 'root', '',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT nom FROM jeux_video WHERE possesseur = ?');
$req->execute(array($_GET['possesseur']));

    while($data = $req->fetch()){
        echo $data['nom'].'<br/>';
    }

$req->closeCursor();
```

## ?>

and this is the error:

Notice: Undefined index: possesseur in /opt/lampp/htdocs/openclassroom/index.php on line 12

Comment: This is not a sql error, it's a php error. Your $_GET doesn't have an index named 'possesseur' if you read the error you'd know

Answer (score 0):

The variable "possesseur" is not passed in the URL like that

```
script.php?possesseur=TEST
```

It is not a Mysql error, it is a PHP notice

Answer (score 0):

```
$req->execute(array($_GET['possesseur']));
```

You're not checking if $_GET['possesseur'] exists. Add an if clause in it:

```
<?php
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8', 'root', '',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
 if (isset($_GET['possesseur'])) {
     $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT nom FROM jeux_video WHERE possesseur = ?');
     $req->execute(array($_GET['possesseur']));

    while($data = $req->fetch()){
        echo $data['nom'].'<br/>';
    }

    $req->closeCursor();
 }
```